# Why is my Slave not starting on MYSQL?

Tags: mysql, database, linux, unix, replication

```
mysql> start slave;
Query OK, 0 rows affected, 1 warning (0.00 sec)

mysql> show warnings;
+-------+------+--------------------------+
| Level | Code | Message                  |
+-------+------+--------------------------+
| Note  | 1254 | Slave is already running |
+-------+------+--------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> show slave status\G;
Empty set (0.00 sec)

ERROR:
No query specified
```

Why???? I did a fresh install of MYSQL. I edited My.cnf. And I restarted the damn things.

This is my slave MY.CNF

```
server-id               = 2
log_bin                 = /var/log/mysql/mysql-bin.log
master-host     = 68.13.41.41
master-user     = replication
master-password = slave
master-port     = 3306
```

This is my master MY.cnf:

```
server-id               = 1
log_bin                 = /var/log/mysql/mysql-bin.log
binlog-do-db=fal
```

I did this on  master:

```
GRANT ALL ON *.* TO 'replication'@'theip' IDENTIFIED BY 'slave';
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it by running commands in the MYSQL thing (instead of relying on the config)

Comment: I know this is old. But I have the same problem. Care to elaborate?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this line to your MY.CNF on the SLAVE server:

*report-host     = 68.13.41.41*

Then restart MySQL on the SLAVE server.

Now test on the MASTER server:

SHOW SLAVE STATUS \G

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you are adding a  semi-colon (;) to the end of the statement.
Its unnecessary with the \G.

So change `show slave status \G;` to `show slave status \G`